Coloured headings in margins, volume 2 (spacing issues)
Let us use this excellent, award-winning answer by Jasper Habicht and put some strange constructions into it. That is when some weird spacing issues around the headings will start to appear:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{l3draw, enumitem, xcolor}

\setlrmargins{7cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.0cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook { shipout/background } {
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \color_select:n { red }
        \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { -1cm , -\paperheight - 1cm } { 6cm , \paperheight + 1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \marginsection } { m } {
    \vspace*{5pt}
    \hspace{-1.5cm}
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \color_select:n { red!50!black }
            \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0cm , -6pt } { 7cm , \baselineskip + 6pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_scope_end:
        \color_select:n { white }
        \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { \linewidth } { \centering #1 }
        \draw_transform_shift:n { 1.5cm , 0.5 * ( \baselineskip - 6pt ) }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { vc } { l }
    \draw_end:
    \vspace*{5pt}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { margintext } { +b } {
    \AddToHookNext { shipout/background } {
        \draw_begin:
            \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
            \color_select:n { white }
            \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { #1 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { .5cm , -.5cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { t } { l }
        \draw_end:
    }
} { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{margintext}
    Hello World.
                
    \marginsection{A section}
    
    More hello world.
    
    \marginsection{Another section}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Something.
        \item[Second] Something else.
        \item[Third] Something different.
    \end{itemize}
    
    \marginsection{Yet another section}
    
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some flushleft content.
        
        This is for the cases where hyphenation is, for one reason or another, undesired.
    \end{flushleft}
\end{margintext}

Hello World

\end{document}


Also, as you can see, there is a colour issue with the item labels, but it only appears when loading xcolor. Apparently, \color_select:n { white } isn’t enough to make the labels white. (I may mention that \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { \color{white} #1 } does provide an (ugly) solution to the problem, but can it be done in a better way?)
Actually, what I really want to do in the end is set \parskip=1em in the margin text. I tried doing \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { \parskip=1em #1 }, but I don’t know if there are “cleaner” solutions? Anyway, the result becomes even uglier:
% same code as before

\NewDocumentEnvironment { margintext } { +b } {
    \AddToHookNext { shipout/background } {
        \draw_begin:
            \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
            \color_select:n { white }
            \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { \parskip=1em #1 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { .5cm , -.5cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { t } { l }
        \draw_end:
    }
} { }

% same code as before



I seem to have solved the issue by using the same commands that LaTeX uses around ordinary headings. Still, the TeX gurus are very welcome to tell me if there are cleaner solutions:
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{l3draw, enumitem, xcolor}

\setlrmargins{7cm}{*}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{2.0cm}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook { shipout/background } {
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \color_select:n { red }
        \draw_path_rectangle_corners:nn { -1cm , -\paperheight - 1cm } { 6cm , \paperheight + 1cm }
        \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
    \draw_end:
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \marginsection } { m } {
    \removelastskip
    \vspace*{10pt}
    \hspace{-1.5cm}
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \color_select:n { red!50!black }
            \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0cm , -6pt } { 7cm , \baselineskip + 6pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_scope_end:
        \color_select:n { white }
        \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { \linewidth } { \centering #1 }
        \draw_transform_shift:n { 1.5cm , 0.5 * ( \baselineskip - 6pt ) }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { vc } { l }
    \draw_end:
    \vspace*{10pt}
    \use:c { @afterindentfalse }
    \use:c { @afterheading }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { margintext } { +b } {
    \AddToHookNext { shipout/background } {
        \draw_begin:
            \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
            \color_select:n { white }
            \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { #1 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { .5cm , -.5cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { t } { l }
        \draw_end:
    }
} { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{margintext}
    Hello World.
                
    \marginsection{A section}
    
    More hello world.
    
    \marginsection{Another section}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Something.
        \item[Second] Something else.
        \item[Third] Something different.
    \end{itemize}
    
    \marginsection{Yet another section}
    
    \begin{flushleft}
        Some flushleft content.
        
        This is for the cases where hyphenation is, for one reason or another, undesired.
    \end{flushleft}
\end{margintext}

Hello World

\end{document}


According to the memoir manual, \abnormalparskip{1em} is better than \parskip=1em, so to accomplish the second part, the following is probably the best solution:
% same code as before

\NewDocumentCommand { \marginsection } { m } {
    \removelastskip
    \vspace*{5pt}
    \hspace{-1.5cm}
    \draw_begin:
        \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
        \draw_scope_begin:
            \color_select:n { red!50!black }
            \draw_path_rectangle:nn { 0cm , -6pt } { 7cm , \baselineskip + 6pt }
            \draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }
        \draw_scope_end:
        \color_select:n { white }
        \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { \linewidth } { \centering #1 }
        \draw_transform_shift:n { 1.5cm , 0.5 * ( \baselineskip - 6pt ) }
        \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { vc } { l }
    \draw_end:
    \vspace*{5pt}
    \use:c { @afterindentfalse }
    \use:c { @afterheading }
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { margintext } { +b } {
    \AddToHookNext { shipout/background } {
        \draw_begin:
            \bool_set_false:N \l_draw_bb_update_bool
            \color_select:n { white }
            \vcoffin_set:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { 5cm } { \abnormalparskip{1em} \color{white} #1 }
            \draw_transform_shift:n { .5cm , -.5cm }
            \draw_coffin_use:Nnn \l_tmpa_coffin { t } { l }
        \draw_end:
    }
} { }

% same code as before


